# CAST DECIMAL to INT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do this:

```
SELECT CAST(columnName AS INT), moreColumns, etc
FROM myTable
WHERE ...
```

I've looked at the help FAQs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html , it says I can do it like `CAST(val AS TYPE)`, but it's not working.

Trying to convert a decimal to int, real value is 223.00 and I want 223

Comment: The warning of casting is because you are supplying a string, can you confirm that?

Comment: Its working even with maria DB also

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You could try the [FLOOR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) function like this:

```
SELECT FLOOR(columnName), moreColumns, etc 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ...
```

You could also try the [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function, provided you know the decimal places can be omitted:

```
SELECT FORMAT(columnName,0), moreColumns, etc 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ...
```

You could combine the two functions

```
SELECT FORMAT(FLOOR(columnName),0), moreColumns, etc 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ...
```

Comment: You realise that you shouldn't be dealing with formatting in your SQL code right?

Comment: Nice work, +1. Format works for my situation fine, but I'm still wondering if anyone can do it with CAST

Comment: @TomMedley: Yeah I wouldn't if I was using PHP aswell, but this is just for some triggers and functions

Comment: @TomMedley I'd be more nuanced: Formatting in the SQL query comes in handy when creating views.

Comment: This adds commas as thousands separators to the number.

Comment: Please note that `FLOOR()` will remove the fractional part of the decimal, but will NOT cast the decimal to a an integer, as the orignal question is asking. The other answer that suggests `decimal_column DIV 1` will cast to an integer. You may want to use `FLOOR()`, `CEILING()`, `ROUND()` or whatever inside that to determine the way the decimal fraction is handled if present.

Answer (score 32):

A more optimized way in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) for this purpose*:

```sql
SELECT columnName DIV 1 AS columnName, moreColumns, etc
FROM myTable
WHERE ...
```

Using **[DIV](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) 1** is a [huge speed improvement](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com.es/2008/07/mysql-divide-and-conquer.html) over **FLOOR**, not to mention string based functions like **FORMAT**

[image: Speed of MySQL integer division Bar Chart] (graphic from Roland Bouman's blog)

```sh
mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(10000000,1234567 DIV 7) ;
+-----------------------------------+
| BENCHMARK(10000000,1234567 DIV 7) |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                 0 |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.83 sec)

mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(10000000,1234567 / 7) ;
+---------------------------------+
| BENCHMARK(10000000,1234567 / 7) |
+---------------------------------+
|                               0 |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (7.26 sec)

mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(10000000,FLOOR(1234567 / 7)) ;
+----------------------------------------+
| BENCHMARK(10000000,FLOOR(1234567 / 7)) |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      0 |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (8.80 sec)
```

(*) NOTE: As pointed by Grbts, be aware of the behaviour of DIV 1 when used with non unsigned/positive values.

Answer (score 24):

From the article you linked to:

> The type can be one of the following values:
>
> BINARY[(N)]
>
> CHAR[(N)]
>
> DATE
>
> DATETIME
>
> DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
>
> SIGNED [INTEGER]
>
> TIME
>
> UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

Try `SIGNED` instead of `INT`

Comment: Thanks but I get another error now: Error code 1292, SQL state 22001: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '558.00'

Answer (score 18):

The CAST() function does not support the "official" data type "INT" in MySQL, it's not in [the list of supported types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast). With MySQL, "SIGNED" (or "UNSIGNED") could be used instead:

```
CAST(columnName AS SIGNED)
```

However, this seems to be MySQL-specific (not standardized), so it may not work with other databases. At least [this document (Second Informal Review Draft) ISO/IEC 9075:1992, Database](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) does not list "SIGNED"/"UNSIGNED" in section `4.4  Numbers`.

But DECIMAL is both standardized and supported by MySQL, so the following should work for MySQL (tested) and other databases:

```
CAST(columnName AS DECIMAL(0))
```

According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html):

> If the scale is 0, DECIMAL values contain no decimal point or
>   fractional part.

Comment: DECIMAL(0) prevents None for python MySQLDb. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

use this

```
mysql> SELECT TRUNCATE(223.69, 0);
        > 223
```

Here's [a link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate)

Answer (score 11):

There is an important difference between floor() and DIV 1. For negative numbers, they behave differently. DIV 1 returns the integer part (as cast as signed does), while floor(x) returns "the largest integer value not greater than x" (from the manual). So : **select floor(-1.1)** results in -2, while **select -1.1 div 1** results in -1

Answer (score 5):

your can try this :

```
SELECT columnName1, CAST(columnName2 AS  SIGNED ) FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also ROUND() if your numbers don't necessarily always end with .00.  ROUND(20.6) will give 21, and ROUND(20.4) will give 20.

Answer (score 1):

Try  `cast (columnName as unsigned)`

unsigned is positive value only

If you want to include negative value, then `cast (columnName as signed)`,
The difference between sign (negative include) and unsigned (twice the size of sign, but non-negative)

Answer (score 0):

1 cent:
no space b/w CAST and (expression).
i.e., CAST(columnName AS SIGNED).