# mySQL Largest number by group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, max

I have messed around with this code for quite sometime.  First thing I have my SQL table setup as char instead of decimal because I don't want the number to always show a decimal value unless it has a decimal value (Is there another way to do this?).  I change it to decimal within my code but I believe this is where the problem lies.  I am trying to pull the largest fish per user per species but it isn't working out.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY CAST(weight AS DECIMAL(9,3)) DESC) tmp WHERE username = :user GROUP BY species
```

EDIT

I have changed my table to use decimal(10,3) instead of char and have been trying this formula

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY CAST(weight AS INT) DESC) tmp WHERE username = 'BooF' GROUP BY species
```

But for some reason it returns this

```
username    location       species  date    length  weight  timestamp   id
BooF    Muskellunge Lake    Black Crappie   2014-08-31  9.125   0.37    2014-12-20 10:48:06 13
BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-07-03  16.75   2.62    2014-12-20 10:49:00 2
BooF    Muskellunge Lake    Northern Pike   2014-08-31  32.75   6.86    2014-12-20 10:49:37 14
BooF    Lake Bonaparte  Rock Bass   2014-09-27  7   0.30    2014-12-20 10:50:50 57
BooF    Lake Ozonia Smallmouth Bass 2014-08-15  13  1.19    2014-12-20 10:51:14 1
BooF    Stark Falls Reservoir   Walleye 2014-08-15  16  0.97    2014-12-20 10:51:37 49
BooF    Lake Bonaparte  Yellow Perch    2014-09-27  8.5 0.40    2014-12-20 10:52:01 56
```

This is the table I am working with

```
username  location      species     date        length  weight  timestamp id
BooF    Lake Ozonia Smallmouth Bass 2014-08-15  13.000  1.190   2014-12-20 10:51:14 1
BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-07-03  16.750  2.620   2014-12-20 10:49:00 2
BooF    Muskellunge Lake    Largemouth Bass 2014-08-31  12.000  1.000   2014-08-31 22:04:42 7
BooF    Muskellunge Lake    Largemouth Bass 2014-08-31  16.000  2.000   2014-08-31 22:04:42 8
BooF    Muskellunge Lake    Largemouth Bass 2014-08-31  14.000  1.000   2014-08-31 22:04:42 9
BooF    Muskellunge Lake    Largemouth Bass 2014-08-31  16.000  2.000   2014-08-31 22:04:42 10
BooF    Muskellunge Lake    Largemouth Bass 2014-08-31  14.000  2.000   2014-08-31 22:04:42 11
BooF    Muskellunge Lake    Largemouth Bass 2014-08-31  16.000  2.000   2014-08-31 22:05:53 12
BooF    Muskellunge Lake    Black Crappie   2014-08-31  9.125   0.370   2014-12-20 10:48:06 13
BooF    Muskellunge Lake    Northern Pike   2014-08-31  32.750  6.860   2014-12-20 10:49:37 14
BooF    Narrow Lake Northern Pike   2014-03-15  20.000  2.000   2014-09-01 11:08:21 15
BooF    Narrow Lake Largemouth Bass 2014-03-15  14.000  1.000   2014-09-01 11:08:21 16
BooF    Butterfield Lake    Largemouth Bass 2014-05-26  19.000  3.000   2014-09-01 11:08:21 17
BooF    Butterfield Lake    Largemouth Bass 2014-05-26  17.000  2.000   2014-09-01 11:08:21 18
BooF    Red Lake    Northern Pike   2014-06-21  22.000  2.000   2014-09-01 11:08:21 19
BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-07-03  15.000  2.000   2014-09-01 11:12:08 20
BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-07-03  15.000  2.000   2014-09-01 11:12:08 21
BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-07-02  17.000  2.000   2014-09-01 11:12:08 22
BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-07-01  15.000  2.000   2014-09-01 11:12:08 23
BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-07-01  15.000  2.000   2014-09-01 11:12:08 24
BooF    Black Lake  Largemouth Bass 2014-06-30  19.250  4.100   2014-12-20 10:53:17 25
BooF    Black Lake  Northern Pike   2014-06-29  26.750  3.940   2014-12-20 10:52:38 26
BooF    Stark Falls Reservoir   Walleye 2014-08-15  16.000  0.970   2014-12-20 10:51:37 49
BooF    Lake Bonaparte  Yellow Perch    2014-09-27  8.500   0.400   2014-12-20 10:52:01 56
BooF    Lake Bonaparte  Rock Bass   2014-09-27  7.000   0.300   2014-12-20 10:50:50 57
```

As you can see after the query it posts a largemouth bass for black lake weighing 2.62 pounds but on my data sheet it shows the largest bass at 4.1 so this is where I am stuck.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Perhaps something like... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537037/cast-decimal-to-int

Comment: Use proper data types when storing data. (If you want some other presentation, use a view for that purpose.)

Comment: Updated with actual data I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general ORDER BY in a sub-query makes no sense. (It only does when combined with FETCH FIRST/LIMIT/TOP etc.)

The solution is to use a correlated sub-query to find the heaviest fish for the "main query"'s current row's username, location, species combination. If it's a tie, both rows will be returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM entries e1
WHERE username = :user
  AND CAST(weight AS DECIMAL(9,3)) = (select max(CAST(weight AS DECIMAL(9,3)))
                                      from entries e2
                                      where e1.username = e2.username
                                        and e1.location = e2.location
                                        and e1.species = e2.species)
```

Note that char for weight is still a bad choice, beacause of that you have to cast both sides when comparing values. Go back to decimal in your table!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I added GROUP BY species at the end of this and it returns results but still not returning heaviest fish.  It seems to be returning the first species it comes to.

Comment: I think I figured it out, I can manipulate what I get by changing whats in the where clause but I guess I dont understand what its doing.