# mySQL largest value by unique entry

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have tried to solve the following problem for the last couple of hours and could not find anything that pointed me in the right direction on Google or Stackoverflow. I believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026906/mysql-largest-number-by-group) could be a similar problem, but I did not really understand what the author wanted to achieve, hence I am trying it with my own concrete example:

I have a table that basically tracks prices of different products over time:

```
+------------+--------+----------+
| Product_id | Price  |   Time   |
+------------+--------+----------+
|          1 |  1.30  | 13:00:00 |
|          1 |  1.10  | 13:30:00 |
|          1 |  1.50  | 14:00:00 |
|          1 |  1.60  | 14:30:00 |
|          2 |  2.10  | 13:00:00 |
|          2 |  2.50  | 13:30:00 |
|          2 |  1.90  | 14:00:00 |
|          2 |  2.00  | 14:30:00 |
|          3 |  1.45  | 13:00:00 |
|          3 |  1.15  | 13:30:00 |
|          3 |  1.50  | 14:00:00 |
|          3 |  1.55  | 14:30:00 |
+------------+--------+----------+
```

I would now like to query the table so that the rows with max. Price for each product are returned:

```
+------------+--------+----------+
| Product_id | Price  |   Time   |
+------------+--------+----------+
|          1 |  1.60  | 14:30:00 |
|          2 |  2.50  | 13:30:00 |
|          3 |  1.55  | 14:30:00 |
+------------+--------+----------+
```

Also, in case of duplicates, i.e. if there is a max. Price at two different points in time, it should only return one row, preferably the one with the smallest value of time.

I have tried MAX() and GREATEST(), but could not achieve the desired outcome to show the wanted values for each product. Efficiency of the query is not the most important factor, but I have about 500 different products with several million rows of data, hence splitting the table by unique product did not seem like an appropriate solution.

Comment: show us what query you have tried

Comment: Just FYI, this is the single most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag. Sometimes, it's correctly answered too.

Comment: Could you please point me to one of those? I only found questions relating to finding the largest value in one column of the table.

Comment: While the linked question above is not quite relevant. Several questions 'related' to the linked questions are exactly relevant.

Comment: @ CrakC: I tried variations of this query: `SELECT product_id, max(price) FROM table_prices`, but could not find a way to implement a "for each" loop

Comment: @user2606932: check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group the data product id and pick the max price and max time

```
select t1.product_id,t1.price,min(t1.time) as time from your_table t1
inner join (
     select  Product_id,max(price)as price from 
     your_table group by Product_id
) t2 on t1.Product_id=t2.Product_id and t1.price=t2.price group by t1.product_id
```

Sql Fiddle Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/020c3/9

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It gave me the results I was looking for quite quickly on my large table. There have initially been negative comments on your first attempts, but I assume they do not relate to the most recent version of your code. Or would there be a scenario where this proposed solution creates issues?

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/020c3/1

```
SELECT p.*
FROM prices p
LEFT JOIN prices p1
ON p.product_id = p1.product_id
AND p.time<p1.time
WHERE p1.product_id IS NULL
```

If you need maximum price to get you can:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/020c3/6

```
SELECT p.*
FROM prices p
LEFt JOIN prices p1
ON p.product_id = p1.product_id
AND p.price<p1.price
WHERE p1.product_id IS NULL;
```

And the last approach since I didn't get the goal from the beggining:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ace04/2

```
SELECT p.*
FROM prices p
LEFt JOIN prices p1
ON p.product_id = p1.product_id
AND (
  p.price<p1.price
  OR  (p.price=p1.price AND p.time<p1.time)
)
WHERE p1.product_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: maybe I misunderstodd, but shouldn't it be last price? according to the time?

Comment: @LukasEder No, but the OP may be able to adapt it (at least to answer the first part of the question)

Comment: The question is crystal clear if you ask me :) The correct solution would compare *both* price *and* time. I'm intrigued by the anti-join via outer join and `IS NULL` predicate. What's the advantage of this approach compared to `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped me to get a better understanding of how to use JOIN statements in mySQL queries in this context. It yielded the desired result, however, in terms of performance on my 5GB table Code-Monk's proposed answer worked significantly quicker.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is assuming the existence of an additional `my_table.id` column that needs to be used in case there are duplicate values for `(Product_id, price, time)` in your table. `id` is assumed to be a unique value in the table.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM my_table t2
  WHERE t1.Product_id = t2.Product_id
  AND ((t1.price < t2.price) OR 
       (t1.price = t2.price AND t1.time > t2.time) OR
       (t1.price = t2.price AND t1.time = t2.time AND t1.id > t2.id))
)
```

Alternatively, the predicate on price and time could also be expressed using a row value expression predicate (not sure if it's more readable, as `t1` and `t2` columns are mixed in a each row value expression):

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM my_table t2
  WHERE t1.Product_id = t2.Product_id
  AND (t1.price, t2.time, t2.id) < (t2.price, t1.time, t1.id)
)
```

Comment: inadequately deals with tie break conditions

Comment: Yes, I understand that. And I said that there needs to be an additional unique criteria (or a unique constraint over the existing fields). With what we have from the OP, the "tie-break" can't be "fixed", albeit, that might also be OK given the requiements

Comment: @Drew: `DISTINCT` is a bad idea for a variety of reasons. I fixed the answer to also include an additional unique ordering criteria

Comment: Thanks for your response and for introducing me to row value expression predicates, about which I just read on your blog. As with Alex's response, your answer gave me the expected results, but it took longer to process on my rather large dataset.