# Using 'Greater than' operator with a negative number

Tags: mysql, negative-number, comparison-operators

I need to run several queries against columns containing both positive and negative numbers and return all rows that are either `<` or `>` than a selected value, however it's not returning the expected results when I use a 'Greater than' operator if the selected value is a negative number.

Please note that when the selected value is a negative number it should be returning both positive and negative numbers, and it seems to be excluding the negative numbers from the results.

```
SELECT T3.*    
FROM Rules T3
WHERE T3.Width > '-.80';
```

The values contained in T3.Width are:

> 0.90,(0.70),(0.70),(0.70),(0.70),(1.00),(1.00),(1.00),(1.00),(0.90),(0.55),(0.50)

Therefore the result should be:

> 0.90,(0.70),(0.70),(0.70),(0.70),(0.55),(0.50)

However the result being returned is:

> 0.90

Comment: Try to cast the SELECT query as SIGNED: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537037/cast-decimal-to-int

Comment: What's the data type of the `Width` column?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - The data type is VarChar (which I'd rather keep if possible)

Comment: The column values literally have the surrounding `()` then?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - The code that I'm currently testing does. It hadn't even occurred to me that could be an issue :-( Is that a problem?

Comment: @VladimirRamik - Would you mind elaborating a bit? I actually saw that post earlier, but I'm not really clear how it relates to what I'm doing.

Comment: Ok - I take it the () are negative values then. MySQL (I'm assuming MySQL?) isn't treating them that way -- they're being handled as strings. If you don't mind some string manipulation with `REPLACE()`, that can be taken care of.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - I just went in and manually changed them, and it's now returning all of the values (including one's which don't match the query)

Comment: Ok - I was working out an answer to handle their conversion inside a query, but if you've solved it you can either post that as an answer yourself or remove the question I suppose.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - I meant that it was returning all 12 rows, instead of the 7 rows that actually match the query ;-) I just edited my answer to hopefully make that clearer to others.

Comment: @ChayaCooper I see ,and I walked away from my computer after that comment yesterday. You will need to CAST() them  - I fleshed it out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is of course to use a `DECIMAL()` or `FLOAT` column in the table.

Since you are working with `VARCHAR()` types and prefer to continue working with `VARCHAR`, the RDBMS is not correctly treating `()` enclosed values as negatives, and instead attempting to cast the strings to an integer (which results in zero, and an incorrect comparison).

#### Working around the `()` enclosed negatives:

Using the `()`-enclosed negative values, you can `REPLACE()` the opening `(` with a `-` and `REPLACE()` the closing `)` with nothing, resulting in a value like `-0.70`, but it is still a *string* to MySQL. You must then [`CAST` it to a decimal value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) for the `< >` comparison.

```
SELECT Width
FROM T3
WHERE
  /* Replace the ( to -, and the ) with nothing
   * then cast it to a decimal value
   */ 
  CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Width, '(', '-'), ')', '') AS DECIMAL(10,2)) > '-0.8'
```

[Example in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42e25/6)

#### Working with regular negative values in a VARCHAR column

If you change them to regular negative numbers but retain the `VARCHAR` type, you don't need all the nested `REPLACE()` but you will still need to cast it to a `DECIMAL(10,2)`.

```
SELECT Width
FROM T3
WHERE 
  CAST(Width AS DECIMAL(10,2)) > '-0.8'
```

[Example 2:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec2be/1)

Answer (score 1):

your forcing a text comparison

```
SELECT T3.*    
FROM Rules T3
WHERE T3.Width > -.80;
```

uses a numerical comparison, The differnce being `'-.80'` vs `-.80` is just the quotes.

When you compare by numerical value the query will return the expected results

if you HAVE to use quotes, use `CAST('-.80' AS DECIMAL(12,2))`

This gives 2 decimal places and 10 digits, Should be enough for most casts, though adjust if needed

> If both arguments in a comparison operation are strings, they are
>   compared as strings.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: Casting `'-.80' `to `SIGNED` will result in `0`.

Comment: This works when I remove the parenthesis (either manually or using @MichaelBerkowski's solution), so it explains why I suddenly couldn't do something that I've done before ;-) And it'll definitely come in handy down the road :-)