# MySQL subtract two columns and compare them to number in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
id | some | irrelevant | data | time | waste_time | logged_in
--------------------------------------------------------------
1  |      |            |      | 0    | 246        | 0
2  |      |            |      | 0    | 360        | 0
3  |      |            |      | 116  | 116        | 0
4  |      |            |      | 291  | 199        | 0
5  |      |            |      | 3997 | 520        | 0
6  |      |            |      | 0    | 175        | 0
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

I am trying to render data from it into multiple `<table>`s, based on the result of `time - waste_time` columns.
I thought I had it working, but I found a bug in my code. If the result is a negative number, then comparing it to 0 (`time - waste_time > 0`) just gets ignored.

Those are my queries:

```
SELECT * FROM players WHERE time-waste_time > 0 OR logged_in=1 ORDER BY logged_in DESC, login DESC

SELECT * FROM players WHERE time-waste_time > 0 AND login < $time_limit ORDER BY login DESC

SELECT * FROM players WHERE time-waste_time <= 0 AND logged_in=0 ORDER BY login DESC
```

The first query will show player that has time 0 and waste_time 150, even though `0 - 150 = -150` and `-150 < 0` and the third query will not show such player.
Expected result is, that such player will not be returned by first and second query, but will be returned by the third one.

I already found this answer: [Using 'Greater than' operator with a negative number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934515/using-greater-than-operator-with-a-negative-number) but it did not help.

Any ideas why is it acting like this and how can I make it work?

Ps.: **`logged_in` IS ZERO**

Thanks.

Comment: you have `>0` in the first query, therefore `-150>0` is FALSE and the row gets dropped from the result...

Comment: But thats not what is happening... it still shows that row.

Comment: yes, because you also have an `or`, so if EITHER of the conditions is true, then the record gets included.

Comment: Read what I told McAdam. Thats result is 0, Ill just add it to table in my question... Please, don't think I would write here without me checking all possible stuff for at least one hour.

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB it's not uncommon for people to post here and find simple mistakes. It happens all the time, and it's perfectly okay. Having a second set of eyes is some of the best help you can get in programming. Don't feel insulted that we checked the basics first.

Comment: Im sorry for that guys. I'm just annoyed by this thing and have no idea whats going on for more than hour. I think its transfering result to string or something like that. But I already checked the basics at least 15 times...

Comment: I can run this in SQL Fiddle and I get all of the expected values using the first and third query, so it would be helpful to see exactly the row that's giving you trouble, if possible for you to share. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77ead/2

Comment: @McAdam331 I added the image to end of my question. On this picture are two (of multiple other similar) rows (with red "dots" next to them) which are giving me trouble.

Comment: And those rows are returned by your first query, and not the third?

Comment: Exactly... And I just found a problem... Those fields where set as UNSIGNED. But why the hell is that a problem? The fields themselves do not have negative values in them... Da F?

Comment: I don't know, and I copied all of this into MySQL and I can't recreate the issue, so I'm at a loss, I'd have to see it to believe it.

Comment: @McAdam331 Here are the links. Working -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6dbd/1 | and NotWorking -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80bbc/1 | Try to notice the difference. I think this is a BUG in SQL itself. This should not be happening.

Comment: Your second `SQLFiddle` is reporting an error of: `Data truncation: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`db_9_80bbc`.`mytable`.`time` - `db_9_80bbc`.`mytable`.`waste_time`)'`, Which may be understandable?

Comment: If you read my answer, you will see that if you use two UNSIGNED fields and subtract them, you will get error if result of such subtraction is negative number. I always thought such setting really matters only for data inside table itself, but well, it does not.

Comment: I agree with you that, as you are not storing it anywhere, then it would be nice if it treated it as a signed number. However, i suspect it would complicate the database programmers job 'significantly'. I agree is is 'unexpected behaviour' and will take a while to find the error. ;-/ Thanks for bring it to our attention. It would have caught me out ;-/

Comment: No problem. At least now I know about this and hopefully others with same problem will be able to find this topic pretty quickly.

Comment: Actually right now I have no idea what are you talking about :D Did you read my answer here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like if you use UNSIGNED fields and result of their subtraction in SQL query is negatve, it will give you error, even when fields itself do not contain negative values.

You can try this code in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80bbc/1

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(200),
  time INT(11) UNSIGNED,
  waste_time INT(11) UNSIGNED,
  logged_in TINYINT(3));

INSERT INTO myTable (name, time, waste_time, logged_in) VALUES ("test1", 0, 246, 0);
INSERT INTO myTable (name, time, waste_time, logged_in) VALUES ("test2", 0, 360, 0);
INSERT INTO myTable (name, time, waste_time, logged_in) VALUES ("test3", 116, 116, 0);
INSERT INTO myTable (name, time, waste_time, logged_in) VALUES ("test4", 291, 199, 0);
INSERT INTO myTable (name, time, waste_time, logged_in) VALUES ("test5", 3997, 520, 0);
INSERT INTO myTable (name, time, waste_time, logged_in) VALUES ("test6", 0, 125, 0);
```

And this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE time - waste_time > 0 OR logged_in = 1;

SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE time - waste_time <= 0 AND logged_in = 0;
```

Now, here is version without UNSIGNED INT fields: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6dbd/1

The way to fix it is either to not use UNSIGNED integers, or when doing such comparison, cast the result to `SIGNED` integer

```
CAST((time - waste_time) AS SIGNED)
```

Comment: Glad you figured that out, I would have never guessed that.

Comment: This is not a bug in MySQL, but a characteristics of the types. The subtraction of two unsigned numbers is another unsigned number, which for all intents and purposes is positive. You can work around it by not using unsigned columns, or by casting the result to a signed integer `CAST((time - waste_time) AS SIGNED)`

Comment: Well, its just weird, but I guess you are right about that. I will stick with not having them as ``UNSIGNED`` for now. But I am glad we finally managed to crack this nut.

Comment: Me too, I wish I could have been of more help, but I definitely learned something interesting today.

Comment: Well, You gave me hope that I could fix it. Othervise I think i would just go to watch some movies :D Also, we learn new stuff every day. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your first query is that you are using the `OR` keyword.

Any rows will be selected where (time - waste_time) is positive, `OR` where logged_in = 1`. In your example, the player with an end value of -150 will still be returned as long as logged_in = 1.

Comment: I know about that, logged in is 0 for those results. I am trying to fix it for more tan hour and those were first things I checked. Another thing is, as I told, it shows it in first query, but does not in third where it should....

Comment: The only way that's possible is if logged_in is equal to 1. I would check your data very closely. If you're convinced it's not wrong, then post some sample data and/or an SQL Fiddle and I can try to recreate it.

Comment: Trust me, Logged in is 0. I am checking the data in database on one monitor and result on another one.

Comment: Can you post a few rows of data that are giving you trouble?