# MySQL Query INNER JOIN with aliases

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, entity-attribute-value

I have two tables: `users` and `users_info`

`users` looks like this:

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id | slug     | name  |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 | theploki | Kris  |
+----+----------+-------+
```

and `users_info` looks like this:

```
+----+--------+----------+---------------+
| id | parent | info_key | info_val      |
+----+--------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | 1      | email    | kris@kris.com |
+----+--------+----------+---------------+
|  2 | 1      | age      | 28            |
+----+--------+----------+---------------+
```

I want to `SELECT` a `user` who has `user_info` email = 'kris@kris.com'
-  and -
return ALL `user_info` values and `users` values

Here's the result I'm looking for:

```
+----+----------+-------+---------------+-----+
| id | slug     | name  | email         | age |
+----+----------+-------+---------------+-----+
|  1 | theploki | Kris  | kris@kris.com | 28  |
+----+----------+-------+---------------+-----+
```

So far the closest I've gotten is with this query:

```
SELECT users.*, users_info.* FROM users
INNER JOIN users_info on users_info.parent = users.id
where users.id = (SELECT users_info.parent FROM users_info
    WHERE users_info.parent = users.id
    AND users_info.info_val = 'kris@kris.com')
```

And it returns this result:

```
+----+----------+-------+----+--------+----------+---------------+
| id | slug     | name  | id | parent | info_key | info_val      |
+----+----------+-------+----+--------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | theploki | Kris  |  1 |  1     | email    | kris@kris.com |
+----+----------+-------+----+--------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | theploki | Kris  |  2 |  1     | age      | 28            |
+----+----------+-------+----+--------+----------+---------------+
```

Obviously I don't need the `id` of the `users_info` result and I want each `info_key` to be the "alias" (or column name) and each `info_val` to be the value for that "alias".

Comment: You cannot write a single SQL statement that can dynamically generate differing number of columns. You would need to create a program that finds the available info_key's for any given parent, and then dynamically generates a SQL statement to format the data to your liking. Your question has been posed before - [search for dynamic EAV](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+dynamic+eav)

Comment: Show us what you are expecting, it'll be easier to correct your query. Just create another array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Rows to Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Comment: I can do this in a stored proc you call, like `call uspGetStuff('kris@kris.com');` ... 1 row output, as horizontal as you want it to go. Best I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you can do it like this;) Just a simple table pivot.

```
select
    users.id,
    users.slug,
    users.name,
    max(if(users_info.info_key = 'email', users_info.info_val, null)) as email,
    max(if(users_info.info_key = 'age', users_info.info_val, null)) as age
from users
inner join users_info
on users.id = users_info.parent
group by users.id
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d194/5)

If you have a dynamic `info_key`, you will need a dynamic sql to do this, here I give you a sample.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(if(users_info.info_key = ''',
      users_info.info_key,
      ''', users_info.info_val, null)) as ',
      users_info.info_key
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM users
inner join users_info
on users.id = users_info.parent
;

SET @sql = CONCAT('select users.id, users.slug, users.name, ', @sql, ' FROM users
inner join users_info group by users.id having email = \'kris@kris.com\'');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d194/13)

Answer (score 1):

This utilizes a change in the schema to support **casting** of data coming back. And it hinges on the use of a stored procedure.

The maximum value of `group_concat` is governed by your setting for the following variable (which is usually defaulted rather low, like 1K):

```
set session group_concat_max_len = 20000;
```

Embed that call at the top of your stored proc under BEGIN. The manual page is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len). The value can be huge. For instance, at least 4GB.

### Schema

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    slug varchar(100) not null,
    name varchar(100) not null
    -- other indexes here like uniqueness, etc (btw none added)
);

drop table if exists users_info;
create table users_info
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    parent int not null,
    info_key varchar(100) not null,
    info_val varchar(100) not null,
    datatype varchar(100) not null, -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8537070/ (DATA TYPES)
    -- other indexes here (btw none added)
    -- FK below:
    foreign key `ui_2_users_9283` (parent) references users(id) -- I guess
);
```

Load Test data;

```
-- delete from users; -- note truncate disallowed on parent with an FK (so delete !)
insert users(slug,name) values 
('theploki','Kris'),
('Yoda','Yoda');
-- select * from users;

-- truncate table users_info;
insert users_info(parent,info_key,info_val,datatype) values 
(1,'email','kris@kris.com','char(100)'),
(1,'age','28','unsigned'),
(2,'birthdate','1996-02-14','date'),
(2,'email','yoda@starwars.com','char(100)'),
(2,'networth','102504.12','decimal(12,2)'),
(2,'age','910','unsigned');
```

Stored Procedure:

```
drop procedure if exists fetchInfoKeysByEmailAddr;
DELIMITER $$
create procedure fetchInfoKeysByEmailAddr(emailAddr varchar(100))
BEGIN
    set @parentid=-1;
    select parent into @parentid 
    from users_info 
    where info_key='email' and info_val=emailAddr;

    if @parentid>0 then
        -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/8537070/ (DATA TYPES)

        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat('cast("',info_val,'" as ',datatype,') as ',info_key)
        ORDER BY info_key SEPARATOR ',')  into @tail
        FROM users_info
        where parent=@parentid
        GROUP BY parent;

        set @final:=concat("select id,slug,name,",@tail,' from users where id=',@parentid);

        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @final;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
    end if;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```
call fetchInfoKeysByEmailAddr('x');
-- user info does not exist, empty (todo: change accordingly)

call fetchInfoKeysByEmailAddr('kris@kris.com');
+----+----------+------+-----+---------------+
| id | slug     | name | age | email         |
+----+----------+------+-----+---------------+
|  1 | theploki | Kris |  28 | kris@kris.com |
+----+----------+------+-----+---------------+

call fetchInfoKeysByEmailAddr('yoda@starwars.com');
+----+------+------+-----+------------+-------------------+-----------+
| id | slug | name | age | birthdate  | email             | networth  |
+----+------+------+-----+------------+-------------------+-----------+
|  2 | Yoda | Yoda | 910 | 1996-02-14 | yoda@starwars.com | 102504.12 |
+----+------+------+-----+------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Due to the `cast` call embedded in the select, the data is brought back in its native, anticipated data type. Which means you can work on it directly.