# AS statement in SQL with the value of another cell

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue with this SQL query, though I think it's mainly a syntax issue.

```
"SELECT grantYear, grantAmount AS /?\
FROM granttoassociation 
JOIN grantprovider ON granttoassociation.grantProvider  = grantprovider.id 
WHERE grantReceiver = ? "
```

I would like the `grantAmount` column to be returned under the name of the corresponding `grantProvider`, which can be found under `grantProvider.name` column in the `grantprovider table`.

(so in the end there would be one column returned for each different `grantProvider.name`)

So what should I put instead of the /?\ in my code ? `grantProvider.name` doesn't seem to be working.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT grantYear, grantAmount, grantprovider.name 
FROM granttoassociation JOIN grantprovider 
ON grantProvider = grantprovider.id 
WHERE grantReceiver = 2891
```

Result:

```
grantYear   grantAmount     name    
2009        3000            besancon
2010        1000            besancon
2011        0               besancon
```

Comment: The comment by @MatBailie sounds right, but could you show us some input and output so that we may be certain?

Comment: You can't, not just with MySQL.  The relational database structure for that would be to have 3 columns; `Provider, Year, Amount`.  Then you get a new row for each `Provider` for each `Year`.  If you want to *PIVOT* that to one row per `Year` then you need to know a fixed list of Providers, which doesn't fit your description.  In which case you need code-that-writes-sql to generate that indeterminate number of columns.  At that point it's a code-smell; you're probably aiming for the wrong thing.  If this is for Presenting data, don't do it in SQL, do it in your application's presentation layer.

Comment: I see. I edited my question with an exemple of input output just in case.

Comment: There is probably just about nothing you can't [do](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38045279). The question is, how miserable of performance are you looking for.

Comment: I did as @MatBailie suggested and did the data manipulation elsewhere.